# Extending rules using SPectral

Tags: yaml, static-analysis, jsonpath, openapi, spectral

I am following [Spectral's documentation](https://stoplight.io/p/docs/gh/stoplightio/spectral/docs/getting-started/rulesets.md) and I am trying to add my custom rule as an extension to `oas3` ruleset, it looks like rule from the documentation is completely ignored.

My OpenApi 3.0 spec file:

```
openapi: 3.0.2
info:
  title: Project info
  description: |
    Project description
  contact:
    name: Test Testable
    email: test@test.test
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
- url: http://localhost:8080
tags:
- name: test-tag
paths:
  /test:
    get:
      tags:
      - test-tag
      summary: Some summary
      operationId: operationId
      description: Operation description
      responses:
        200:
          description: OKK
```

My `.spectral.yml` file:

```
extends: spectral:oas3
rules:
  my-rule-name:
    description: Tags must have a description.
    given: $.tags[*]
    then:
      field: description
      function: truthy
```

My API spec contains `tags` but the tag which is there doesn't have any description so it should fail but it doesn't:

```
>spectral lint api.yml

OpenAPI 3.x detected
No errors or warnings found!
```

Even if I try to change to `function: falsy` which I expect it should fail in one of these 2 cases - still no warnings and no errors. It looks like this rule is just not applied at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. There is a field `recommended: true` needed in rule definition. Documentation mentions it but somehow too briefly:

Updated `.spectral.yml`:

```
extends: spectral:oas3
rules:
  my-rule-name:
    description: Tags must have a description.
    given: $.tags[*]
    recommended: true
    then:
      field: description
      function: truthy
```

and output:

```
13:3  warning  my-rule-name  Tags must have a description.

✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning, 0 infos)
```